# what is the different with Option as_ref and as_deref in Rust

Tags: rust

Now I am using the rust code snippet like this:

```
let stackoverflow = format!("{}{}{}","\\social[stackoverflow]{",request.cv_main.stackoverflow.as_deref().unwrap_or_default(),"}\n");
```

and this is the request cv_main defined:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use super::{edu::edu::CvEduResp, work::cv_work_resp::CvWorkResp};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default, Clone)]
pub struct CvMainResp {
    pub id: i64,
    pub cv_name: String,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub user_id: i64,
    pub cv_status: i32,
    pub template_id: i64,
    pub employee_name: Option<String>,
    pub birthday: Option<String>,
    pub phone: Option<String>,
    pub email: Option<String>,
    pub stackoverflow: Option<String>,
    pub github: Option<String>,
    pub blog: Option<String>,
    pub edu: Option<Vec<CvEduResp>>,
    pub work: Option<Vec<CvWorkResp>>,
}
```

this code works fine, but I am still could not understand why here need to use `as_deref()`. I have read the article https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/rust-asref-asderef/, still did not figure out. does there any simple explain the different with as_ref and as_deref?

Comment: From the linked post: "as_deref works just like as_ref, but additionally performs a deref method call on the value" what's unclear about that? You need it when the type has to change as in from `&String` to `&str`. To give a more tailored answer you'd need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Called on an `Option<String>`, `as_ref()` returns an `Option<&String>`. `as_deref()` on the other hand returns `Option<&str>`, which you could also obtained with `.map(|s| s.as_str())` or `.map(|s| &*s)`. (The latter is generally equivalent to `as_deref()`, and demonstrates `String` "dereferencing" into `str`, which is why it's called `as_deref()`.)

While `Option<&String>` and `Option<&str>` are functionally similar, they are not exactly the same. Here the point of `as_deref()` is to be able to chain it to `.unwrap_or_default()`.

`unwrap_or_default()` can be called on `Option<&str>` because `&str` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#impl-Default-for-%26str) `Default`, `<&str as Default>::default()` just returns the reference to a statically allocated `""` singleton. On the other hand, `Default` is not implemented for `&String`, because it would have to return a reference to a `String` that outlives it, which is not allowed by the borrow checker.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the definition of `Option<T>`'s implementation of `as_deref` method.

```
#[inline]
    #[stable(feature = "option_deref", since = "1.40.0")]
    #[rustc_const_unstable(feature = "const_option_ext", issue = "91930")]
    pub const fn as_deref(&self) -> Option<&T::Target>
    where
        T: ~const Deref,
    {
        match self.as_ref() {
            Some(t) => Some(t.deref()),
            None => None,
        }
    }
```

This method as you can see is only available when `T: Deref` (i am not exactly sure of what ~const does here). And the return type is `Option<&T:Target>`.

In your case `pub stackoverflow: Option<String>`, So `T` is String, String implements `Deref` trait and `T::Deref` gives `str`.

Below is the definition of `as_ref` for `Option<T>`.

```
#[inline]
    #[rustc_const_stable(feature = "const_option_basics", since = "1.48.0")]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    pub const fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        match *self {
            Some(ref x) => Some(x),
            None => None,
        }
    }
```

Here if you see, there is no Trait bound on T and return type is simply Option<&T>.

I hope you can see the difference now. `as_deref` is only available when `T::Deref` and returns `Option<&T::Target>`. Whereas `as_ref` always returns `Option<&T>`.

Comment: `~const` here essentially means "if the `Deref` implementation for `T` is marked `const`, then this function is `const`". This is unstable feature, though, so one probably shouldn't worry about it yet.